# Move row if it contains image src

Tags: jquery, html

I want to move a row below another row if it contains image source Move the row containing image src http://www.aloxi.com/images/continue_button.png below the row containing "Remember me". This needs to be done based on what the row contains not on the table row number because if someone enters the wrong login information then another row is added to the top to display an error message.

```
 <table>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td>
            Password <br>(between 5 and 20 characters)<font color="#FF0000" class="FAFFormRequiredFieldMarker">*</font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="password" id="Password1" maxlength="20" value="" name="password">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
        <td>
            Username:<font color="#FF0000" class="FAFFormRequiredFieldMarker">*</font>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" id="Text1" value="" maxlength="100" name="username">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <td></td>
        <td align="left" style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="faf_rememberme" checked="" value="y" name="faf_rememberme">Remember me
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#6eb9c4">
        <td align="left" colspan="3" style="text-align: left;">
            <b>Enter social media login.</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" style="text-align: left;">
            <br>
            <center>
                <p>
                    <input type="image" border="0" id="Image1" alt="Continue" src="http://www.aloxi.com/images/continue_button.png" name="imageField2">
                </p>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/q5o5g22x/1/
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I originally tried moving based on the table row but because of the sign in error this does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: When you want this happen, on what event?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also, the `<center>` tag was deprecated in the 90's.

Comment: `<font>` elements too. And which row should the image-containing-row be moved beneath (after?) and in response to what?

Comment: No event, this is just how I want it to appear. I am working with a product where you cannot access the HTML to edit it but you can add jquery

Comment: I would like to move it under the row that contains "Remember me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a huge continue button.

Something like this would move it to where you want, but you may want to mess with the CSS to make it look a little nicer...

```
$('#faf_rememberme').closest('tr').after($('#Image1').closest('tr'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0avve1uy/